# how to equate 2 lists and write it as an separate equations in mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation

let 
A = {{1,2},{3,4}}
b = {{a,b},{c,d}}
Now i want to write this list as four equations.
 as a = 1;b=2;c =3; d=4.
So that whenever i take write letter a, it should take value 1.
eqs = MapThread[Thread[#1 == #2] &, {B, A}] // Flatten
i'm getting {a == 1, b == 2, c == 3, d == 4}
but when i write a+b somewhere in code , i'm not getting value 3 , Instead i'm getting a+b 
can you please say what mathematica code i should adopt for this so that i should get value 3 when i write it as a+b i code

Comment: Note that in Mma `a=1` is not an equation, but an assignment. So make it clear please, if you need an equation or an assignment?

Comment: Please go [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your two accounts merged.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
ClearAll[a,b,c,d]
A0  = {{1,2},{3,4}};
B0  = {{a,b},{c,d}};
eqs = MapThread[(#1==#2)&, {B0,A0}, 2] //Flatten
```

gives

```
 {a==1,b==2,c==3,d==4}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want separate *assignment* instead of equations. Simply

```
{{a, b}, {c, d}} = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
```

will do.